# SCNCamera.exposureOffset not working in iOS13

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

SCNCamera.wantsHDR is true. Yet any changes to SCNCamera.exposureOffset are not visible on iOS13 devices. But it is working perfectly fine on iOS12.

```
if let camera = self.sceneView.pointOfView?.camera {
    camera.exposureOffset = -5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said absolutely right, if someone wanna use `exposureOffset` instance property in SceneKit, he/she needs to activate a `wantsHDR` property at first:

```
var wantsHDR: Bool { get set }
```

In real code it might look like this:

```
sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.wantsHDR = true 
sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.exposureOffset = -5
```

But there's a bug in iOS 13 and iOS 13 Simulator. However, if you disable `allowsCameraControl`, exposureOffset works fine.

```
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false
```

> Here's how `exposureOffset` changes from -2 to 2:

[image]